# Unzip file from SDCARD in Android

Tags: android, password-encryption

In my application I encrypted a file from SD card using `PBEWithMD5AndDES` method and encrypted into `.des` format. For example a file `myfile.png` encrypted and converted into `myfile.des` to sdcard. After that I renamed/copied `myfile.des` to `myfile.zip`. Next I need to open zip file ie unziping a file but I am not able unzip. below is my code

```
is = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        ZipEntry ze;

        while((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

             // reading and writing
                while((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, count);                       
                }

                fout.close();               
                zis.closeEntry();
        }

        zis.close();
```

For me the value of `zis.getNextEntry()` is getting null. What is the reason for this null value?

Comment: why is your `FileOutputStream` pointing to the same file of the `FileInputStream`?

Comment: Is that actually a legitimate zip file?  If you adb pull or MTP copy it to your development machine, can you open it as a zip file?   What if you put a known good zip file on the device and try to open it with this as a test?

Comment: @Blackbelt - yes, that doesn't look right, though it won't become an issue until zis.getNextEntry() succeeds once, so there is some other problem too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton depends on how smart is the os/filesystem handling this situation. If the while is executed at least once, he is overwriting the file from where he is reading. Not sure what's gonna happen though

Comment: My reading of the question is that the while is not executed even once (so far) because no zip entries are found in the data.  Your point is one that will need to be fixed, but I think there is another problem gating observing it.  Without being familiar with the components, I'm very suspicious of the sequence of operations which has generated this alleged zip file.

Comment: Have you asked permission to do this? READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton :  It is not entering into while loop. My doubt is, when i encrypt a file then decrypt to .des after that  i am converting it into .zip. Is it good procedure?

Comment: As I said earlier, I'd recommend you pull the file off the device and attempt to open it with known-good zip file tools on your development machine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton :  I pulled into my development machine it is not opening